# Is there a way to upload audio clips?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

It's great to be able to upload images directly for longevity purposes (as opposed to linking to some external site).  Are there any plans for similar functionality for short audio clips on SE sites?  I haven't seen an option, but maybe I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This was requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-se-and-music-se) on meta.SO for the [Audio & Video Production](http://avp.stackexchange.com) site. As [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-se-and-music-se/97610#97610) says, audio clips uploaded to [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com/) and lined to in a post will automatically be converted into an embedded player [like this](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/embedded-audio-player/176#176). Of course, a dev has to turn on the feature for this site, and I'm sure they will when they see this post.

Comment: Sorry, missed this. This will be turned on with the next build.

Comment: @balpha Thanks!